# Is there a standard name for the set of numbers that are rational powers of rationals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, terminology, algebraic-number-theory, rational-numbers

I wonder if there is a name for for the set of numbers that are rational powers of positive rationals.

This is an interesting  restricted subset of the algebraic numbers.

It is clear that this set includes all rationals, and is a multiplicative group, as

$(\frac{a}{b})^\frac{m}{n} (\frac{c}{d})^\frac{r}{r}=(\frac{a^{ms}c^{rn}}{c^{ms}d^{rn}})^{\frac{1}{ns}}$, whit: $a,b,c,d,m,n,r,s$ integers.

But is not closed under addition as for example, as while: $ 1 $ and $\sqrt{2}=2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ belongs to the set, it is impossible to find integers:  $a,b,m,n$ such: $1+\sqrt{2}=(\frac{a}{b})^\frac{m}{n}$

Loosely speaking, it would include all fractions constructed with arbitrary integer indexed roots of integers, and its negatives: (taking into account also the negative result of the even indexed roots of positive numbers)

Comment: Side note: you set is actually all the radicals of positive rational numbers, where by radical I mean an $n$th root for some $n$.

Comment: Yes, that is true,I formulated the question in this way to be  more generic: speaking about rationals instead to restrict exponents to inverses of integers, but both formulations are identical.

Comment: I think the closest thing that is commonly studied to what you are asking is the radical of an ideal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal. So, given a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$, the radical $\sqrt{I}$ is defined as all elements $r\in R$ such that $r^n \in I$ for some $n$. Unfortunately the rationals are not an ideal in the reals, so this doesn't really answer your question.